# How to count the occurrence character in a string in c#?

Tags: c#

How to remove the uppercase char in output? Because I want to count occurrence for lowercase only in C# language.

Comment: You don't have to *modify* the string to count things in it. What about `Char.IsLower`?

Comment: Several answers are assuming you need to count only the total number of characters. It would probably help if you [edit] your question to include *expected output* given the input, rather than just what you're currently getting and what's wrong with it. Counting occurrences per character is quite different, as is treating an uppercase character as its lowercase equivalent rather than listing it separately (if that's what's desired).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IsUpper` function to skip if any character entered by user is upper case. see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isupper?view=net-6.0). Also, you could use dictionary of `char`'s to simplify your approach, and avoid modifying the user input string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the count of each lowercase char within the string, as shown in your output screenshot, you could use a LINQ expression like this:

```cs
string input = "hello World weLcoMe";
IDictionary<char, int> charCounts = input.Where((c) => Char.IsLower(c))
    .GroupBy((c) => c)
    .ToDictionary((item) => item.Key, (item) => item.Count());
foreach(KeyValuePair<char, int> ci in charCounts)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{ci.Key}={ci.Value}");
}

/*
 * Output:
 * h=1
 * e=3
 * l=3
 * o=3
 * r=1
 * d=1
 * w=1
 * c=1
 */
```

**Short Explanation**

You select all lowercase chars with `Where((c) => Char.IsLower(c))`.

Then you group the chars by `GroupBy((c) => c)` (resulting in a collection like `[h] => h, [e] => eee, ...`).

Now a dictionary is created by `ToDictionary((item) => item.Key, (item) => item.Count())` with the char as the key and the char count as the value.

**Edit (based on Jeroen Mosterts comment)**

Without using a dictionary:

```cs
string input = "hello World weLcoMe";
var charCounts = input.Where((c) => Char.IsLower(c))
    .GroupBy((c) => c)
    .Select((item) => new { Key = item.Key, Value = item.Count() });
foreach(var ci in charCounts)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{ci.Key}={ci.Value}");
}
```

Comment: Although creating a dictionary is possible, it's not required; you could simply select a new object using the key and the count, and enumerate the result. This is, in fact, required if the intent is to output the characters in the order they appear in the string, since a dictionary is not guaranteed to preserve that, whereas `GroupBy` is. A fairly technical point given the OP's exercise, but still.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I had use your LINQ expression, and I got the same expected answer. Can I know how to make the user Input the string?

Comment: If I want to input the string by console.readline how ya?

Comment: @ijat If I get you right, just replace `string input = "hello World weLcoMe";` with `string input = Console.ReadLine();`. Than the input from the user is taken.

Comment: Or even `foreach(var h in input.Where(Char.IsLower)
    .GroupBy(c => c)) Console.WriteLine($"{g.Key}={g.Count()}");`

Answer (score -1):

if u want put all chars in string to lower use `ToLower()`

```
string inputString = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
```

then use `Count()` (you need use linq)

---

but is u wont put upper chars to lower and just find count of lower chars without uppers , use `char.IsLower` in `Count()`

```
string inputString = Console.ReadLine().Count(char.IsLower);
```

it will just show count of lower chars , not upper and space

Comment: That is not the requirement for the OP, only the lower case characters need to be counted.